# Sum column from another table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a DB in PostgreSQL with 2 tables, customers and orders:

1. In customers, among all the columns, I have the customer ID (Primary key) and number of orders.
2. In orders, among all the columns, I have the order ID (Primary key) and the customer ID (foreign key)

When I insert a row in orders, I'm doing an update of customers and I do number of orders = number of orders + 1. However, now I will need to delete orders, and I was thinking if there is a better way of having control of number of orders. Is there any constraint I could do that would be beneficial for me?

Can I remove a row in orders and substract 1 in number of orders in a single transaction?

Comment: you can write a trigger for that, but why at all, make a quick select and you have the number on orders

Comment: Do not store the number of orders in the `customer` table. When that  is actually needed derive it either with a query or select it from a view (which derives it). Doing so removes all `customer` maintenance requirements/functionality for any DDL statement on `orders`.  There is **no constraint** to handle this. BTW: In a multiple user *orders = number of orders + 1* is a potential performance killer.